# Replacement for the expression "there are."

Tags: word-choice, grammar, verbs, expressions, phrase-requests

My writing teacher dislikes the expression "there are" in essays/writing. Does anybody know some good substitutes for this *overused* expression? Or a better way to express these words?

Comment: You may find [ell.se] useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Try to take the word after the "there are" as the subject, or object, of the sentence. 
And to find a verb more precise, or on the reverse more general than "are". 
Eventually, to express the idea in a totally different way.**

"There are penguins in Antarctica". -> "Penguins live in Antarctica".

"There are place settings on the table". -> "Place settings lay on the table". -> "The table is laid".

"There are many elderly people in this town". -> "Many elderly people live in this town". -> "The mean age is high in this town".

"There are many motives of disagreement between him and me" -> "We have many motives of disagreement". -> "We disagree on a number of ideas".

Comment: "There are place settings on the table". -/-> "Place settings lay on the table". "There are place settings on the table". -> "Place settings lie on the table".